# Class Cast Exception When Same Jar is Included in WEB-INF/lib and CLASSPATH

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, classcastexception

I have a .jar file added to the CLASSPATH of the JBoss 5 startup (run.bat/run.sh) file. This is a dependency jar which is referred to from the servlet based application. If I use this setup, the servlet loads fine and works as expected. However, I noted that if I have the same jar in the servlet's WEB-INF/lib directory, I get a class cast exception as follows:

```
ERROR [STDERR] ERROR: com.idoox.wasp.ProtocolRepositoryImpl - Exception in protocolHandler soap, protocolHandler com.server.saaj.soap.SOAP11ProtocolHandler, class space root.wasp-impl.SOAP : 
ERROR [STDERR] EXCEPTION: 
ERROR [STDERR] com.systinet.saaj.soap.SOAP11ProtocolHandler cannot be cast to org.idoox.wasp.ProtocolHandler 
ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.ClassCastException: com.server.saaj.soap.SOAP11ProtocolHandler cannot be cast to org.idoox.wasp.ProtocolHandler
```

This is not an issue since I won't have the jar in both places, but I'm just wondering why it is happening this way. Is this a class loading issue?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jar file you are mentioning would be already available with `JBoss`. Whe you place it in the `WEB-INF/lib`; JBoss has already loaded the class from the `jar` available with JBoss and there is conflict with the class in the `web-inf` folder. Classes loaded by different classloaders are treated as different even if the classes are same. 
 When you give in `run.bat` there is only one `jar` file loaded. JBoss loads this and there is no conflicting jars.